# Capistrano deploy in Virtual Machne

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, virtualbox, readonly, vagrant

I using Virtual box + gem Vagrant
One week before everything works well.
I had packaged my box. And now I've deployed the box again with the same project.

and Capistrano has outputted error:

```
*** [err :: 33.33.33.10] creating symbolic link `/vagrant/demoapp/current/log'
*** [err :: 33.33.33.10] : Read-only file system
```

https://gist.github.com/1746250 (error + deploy.rb)

I have set sudo chmod 777 -R 1vagrant/ 
But it still doestn't work.

What happen?

Comment: Is VM filesystem writeable? Can you manually create /vagrant/demoapp/current/log folder? ( same as /vagrant/demoapp/shared/log)

Comment: hi again. yes i can vagrant@lucid32:/vagrant/demoapp/shared$ rm -rf log/       
vagrant@lucid32:/vagrant/demoapp/shared$ mkdir log mkdir  /vagrant/demoapp/current/log         cap deploy - Same error

Comment: hmm, could you check this command: ssh vagrant@33.33.33.10 'ln -s /vagrant/demoapp/shared/log /vagrant/demoapp/current/log' ?

Comment: itsnikolay@itsnikolay-VirtualBox:~/vagrant/1vagrant/projects/demoapp$ ssh vagrant@33.33.33.10 'ln -s /vagrant/demoapp/shared/log /vagrant/demoapp/current/log'
vagrant@33.33.33.10's password: 
ln: creating symbolic link `/vagrant/demoapp/current/log': Read-only file system
itsnikolay@itsnikolay-VirtualBox:~/vagrant/1vagrant/projects/demoapp$ 
Yes, the same error.

Comment: So, you can't modify your vm fs via ssh - here is the reason, it's not a capistrano issue. Could you modify VM FS while logged in under vagrant@33.33.33.10 ?

Comment: People says that its issue appears in mounting shared folders. This line should fix it mount -o remount,rw / . But it doesn't. And I can't understand how it has appear in working environment.

Comment: /etc/fstab https://gist.github.com/1746547  errors=remount-ro 0 probably it's response  for the error?

Comment: No, this device is mounted properly

Comment: Do you have any thought about the physical restriction?

Comment: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=51306 — Haven't read all this topics but smthng could be found here I hope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official answer of Vagrant gem's author:

> The VirtualBox shared folder filesystem doesn't allow symlinks, unfortunately.
>
> Your only option is to deploy outside of the shared folders.

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/713

Answer (score 7):

There is a workaround to make symlinks in shared folders work on VirtualBox 4.1.8+ again.  Basically you need to issue this command:

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
```

You can do this in the context of Vagrant by adding this to the `Vagrant::Config.run` block of your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME", "1"]
```

More information can be found on [VirtualBox bug #10085](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085#comment:12).

Please note the commenter that shares the `setextradata` trick forgets to tell you the key name requires the `SHARE_NAME`.  I found this out [digging through the C code](http://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Main/src-client/ConsoleImpl.cpp)!

Comment: what is the SHARE_NAME ? for example : i have something like this in my vagrantfile : config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/manager"